# How to hide get parameter from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to hide get parameter from url.

I have URL like **domain.com/controller/function?clear=1**

I want to remove ?clear=1 from URl and want to URL like:
**domain.com/controller/function**

it is possible in codeigniter but how ? i saw some similar question here but i can't found proper solution.

Comment: You can't hide a GET parameter, but you can send a POST request instead ?

Comment: ok sir... but i think by using rout we can do it ?

Comment: You also can send a crypted parameter if you do not want the user to see the content of teh param

Comment: You can use the URI Library to achieve what you are looking to do: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: not a content problem but i just want clear URL i just pass that get parameter for my backhand use.. so i want to hide this and i cant use post for some reason

Comment: So you don't want to send a GET parameter and also can't do POST? That's just not possible - why would you even want to hide a GET parameter? Security by obscurity?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to hide the get parameter.
You can use ajax to send the parameter like this

```
        var id = "your parameter which you want to send in the url";
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('controller/function');?>/"+id,
            success:function(data)
            {



            }

            });
        }
```

Try this for more  [link](http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base64_encode` before send data and when you catch that in Controller `base64_decode`

[Examples of Encoding & Decoding Encrypted PHP](https://perishablepress.com/tools/decoding/)

In View

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>Controller_name/Method/<?php base64_encode('Im the value')?>"
```

In Controller

```
public function Method($id)
{
   $valid_id = base64_decode($id);
}
```

Comment: @David did you check this??